# iOS 8.1.2 input ="file" doesn't work in UIWebView

Tags: ios8

I am trying to upload file from a UIWebView that is presented modally.
It works fine in iOS 7 but in iOS8 i have the options to take a picture or choose from existent and when i click in anyone of the options list the web view is dismissed and no file uploaded.

Can anyone help me please?